# How to I tail the STDOUT of a cat command

Tags: linux, bash, cat, file-descriptors

Let's say that I start a `cat` process to wait for some input. e.g.,

```
$ cat > out.log
```

In another terminal, I can identify its PID and feed data into its File Descriptor 0 (zero = STDIN), like this:

```
$  echo "hello" > /proc/2357/fd/0
```

And then the first terminal reacts:

```
$ cat > out.log
hello
```

A couple of questions:
1)The "hello" string shows up in the actual terminal instead of being redirected to the file, is that due to the nature of the `cat` program (it just focuses on the tty/foreground)?

2) I can't tail the STDOUT of that same process:

```
tail -f /proc/2357/fd/1
...
```

Nothing shows up. Any conjectures on what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/proc/2357/fd/0 is file descriptor 0 of the cat process, which is the terminal itself. /proc/2357/fd/1 is file descriptor 1 of the cat process, which you connected to the file out.log.

Now if you echo something to /proc/2357/fd/0, it will go to the terminal, because that's the file the descriptor refers to.

If you echo something to /proc/2357/fd/1, it will go into out.log, but not via cat!

You cannot echo something to the process in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the tee(1) command, which is basically a T-junction for unix commands: it redirects its stdin to both stdout and a file (which you can then tail -F)

Comment: It does sound like an interesting alternative just to play with file descriptors and make all this knowledge more tangible. However.. I wasn't able to achieve what I was looking for with the `tee` command either. I've also tried `cat | tee output.txt` and checked the `stdout = /proc/<PID>/fd/1` of the `tee` process, but there's no reaction in my `tail -f`. Thoughts?